# problem getting the grid right and no background Color

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d

This is my code that attempts to make **400 x 400** grid but outputs the following:
[image]

No doubt this not a **400 x 400** grid.

I am unable to detect where i have got my logic wrong. I have highlighted the part responsible for drawing.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class tester1 extends JPanel {
 tester1() {
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
  this.setBackground(Color.black);
  JFrame fr = new JFrame();
  fr.add(this);
  fr.pack();
  fr.setVisible(true);
  fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  repaint();
 }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {   // <----- part responsible for drawing
   g.setColor(Color.red); 
     for(int x = 0 ; x <= 400 ; x += 10 ) {
       g.drawLine( x , 0 , 400 , x );
     }
     for(int y = 0 ; y <= 400 ; y += 10 ) {
       g.drawLine( y , 0 , y , 400 );
     }
  }   // <---- till here

  public static void main(String args[]) {
     new tester1();
  }
 }
```

What mistake have I made in `paintComponent` method ?

Also in the output why don't I get **BLACK** color as the background, when I have written `this.setBackground(Color.black)`?

Comment: +1 For supplying code & a (well cropped, even) screen shot.  BTW - for screenshots, I put them over a white web page (to have white BG in the corners) then hold 'alt' while pressing the 'print-screen' button.  The 'alt' key ensures that only the focused component is captured, and the white BG in the rounded corners segues in well with any site that uses a white BG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `super.paintComponent()` before you do any painting in order for the background to be painted black.

As far as the lines go:
You have your x and y coordinated mixed up.  It should be: `(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)`

Specifically look at:

```
 g.drawLine( x , 0 , 400 , x );
```

And ask yourself why you are varying one X and one Y and holding the other X and other Y constant.

Where as here:

```
 g.drawLine( y , 0 , y , 400 );
```

You are holding both Ys constant and changing both of the Xs (Hint: your other statement should look like this one.).

Comment: how are my co-ordinates mixed up ? yes though my background is painted black,but what does `super.paintComponent(g)` do ?

Comment: Read about what super does, it is very important in understand Java.   As far as the coordinates go, write them out on paper or do System.out.printlns and think about what you want it to do vs what it is doing now (looking at the coordinates generated.

Comment: can you please explain what does `paintComponent()` do

Comment: paintComponent, is what paints the component on the Graphics object.  Your code has a comment that says "responsible for drawing", next to the method.

Answer (score 2):

I think your current output is v. pretty, but anyway..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class tester1 extends JPanel {
 tester1() {
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
  this.setBackground(Color.black);
  JFrame fr = new JFrame();
  fr.add(this);
  fr.pack();
  fr.setVisible(true);
  fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  repaint();
 }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   // as mentioned by jzd
   super.paintComponent(g);
   g.setColor(Color.red);
     for(int x = 0 ; x <= getWidth() ; x += 10 ) {
       // as mentioned by ditkin
       g.drawLine( x , 0 , x , getHeight() );
     }
   g.setColor(Color.yellow);
     for(int y = 0 ; y <= getHeight() ; y += 10 ) {
       // also this
       g.drawLine( 0 , y , getWidth() , y );
     }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
     new tester1();
  }
 }
```

BTW - unless you call `setResizable(false)` on the frame, use `getHeight()` / `getWidth()` when painting.

### Screenshot

[image: Red/yellow on black grid]

Answer (score -1):

I believe that this line:

```
g.drawLine( x , 0 , 400 , x );
```

Should read:

```
g.drawLine( x , 0 , x, 400);
```

Comment: -1 :then what is the difference between the next for statement ?

Comment: @Meprogrammer: I don't get this -1, was it because ditkin failed to detect *every* error in the code?  (If so) Since when has that been a prerequisite for answering?

Comment: @Andrew, I think the main problem is not that this is just one error, but that changing this line alone would actually make the results look worse for the OP.  (If there was more explanation as to why this line should be changed, that would go a long way.)